# Android: Unable to read serialized object

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a challenge where I have to interact with a system which has an inbuilt app which is sending my app a serialised object.

How am I supposed to read the contents of this object?
I know the structure of the class.
I simply tried
`result.getData().getSerializableExtra('key')`

It returns with an error saying `Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object`

Can you help me out?

Comment: Need more context, do you have the Intent? also result.getData().getSerializableExtra('key') you have single quotes instead of double quotes (I doubt thats it)

Answer (score 0):

> How am I supposed to read the contents of this object? I know the structure of the class.

You need the actual class.  The deserialization code needs to to make an instance of that class, and it can't do it without the code.

> I simply tried `result.getData().getSerializableExtra('key')`
>
> It returns with an error saying `Parcelable` encountered `ClassNotFoundException` reading a `Serializable` object.

Object deserialization requires the actual classes of all of the objects that you are deserializing.  Otherwise it cannot create instances of them.  All of the required classes need to be available *at runtime* so that the classloader can find them.  Because, the deserialization code is going to do the equivalent of `Class.forName(class_name)` for each class in the serialization.

The complete stacktrace should tell you the name of the missing class.

---

> I'm doing a challenge where I have to interact with a system which has an inbuilt app which is sending my app a serialised object.

If part of the challenge is that you need to extract information from the serialized object without having its code ... that is indeed a challenge.

What you would need to do is:

1. Create a class with the same fully qualified name as the missing class and the sane `serialVersionUID`.
2. Add fields to match all of the fields you want to extract from the serialized object.
3. Implement a `readObject` method for the class.  It should call `ObjectInputStream.readFields()` to get the `ObjectInputStream.GetField` object for accessing the serialized fields by name.  Then you use that object to extract values of all of the serialized fields you need and then assign the the values to the the fields of the target object (i.e. `this`).

If this sounds complicated ... it is.  (This is >your< challenge!)

Comment: I know the structure of the class. Is it possible to copy the class into my app and try to retrieve this class? I tried it but it is not working, not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: *"I tried it but it is not working ..."* - It should work.

Comment: I was supposed to copy the entire class as is and keep the package name as the original app package name as well. I was creating a local copy before. I was able to get the class and with some Java reflection got the methods as well. Thanks for the help anyway